# Split row into 2 based on condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV like below. And I want to duplicate row when c2,c3  both are some numbers. Like the last row

```
Initial input
C1,C2,C3
1,2,NaN
1,NaN,3
2,4,5 #both C2C3 not NaN change this row to 2 separate rows



Expected output
C1,C2,C3
1,2,NaN #nochange
1,NaN,3 #nochange
2,NaN,5 #split1
2,4,NaN #split2
```

This looks simple but I'm unable to find a way.

Comment: where is your code you can't fix

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

- filter first by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `df` with removed columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
- create `FloatIndex` for later sorting - new row is always after first one
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) rows with `NaNs` - `~` is for inversing boolean mask
- [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and remove `FloatIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
print (df)
   C1   C2   C3
0   1  2.0  NaN
1   4  7.0  8.0
2   1  NaN  3.0
3   2  4.0  5.0

mask = df['C2'].notnull() & df['C3'].notnull()
df1 = df[mask]
df1 = pd.concat([df1.drop('C2',1), df1.drop('C3',1)])
df1.index = df1.index.where(df1.index.duplicated(keep='last'), df1.index + .1)
print (df1)
     C1   C2   C3
1.0   4  NaN  8.0
3.0   2  NaN  5.0
1.1   4  7.0  NaN
3.1   2  4.0  NaN

df2 = pd.concat([df[~mask], df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
   C1   C2   C3
0   1  2.0  NaN
1   4  NaN  8.0
2   4  7.0  NaN
3   1  NaN  3.0
4   2  NaN  5.0
5   2  4.0  NaN
```

Comment: For simplicity I had just 1 column c1 before c2 c3. I hope having any number of cols before C2C3  would work

Comment: I think yes, maybe ordering of columns can be change. The best try it.

Comment: If ordering is change add [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) - `df2 = pd.concat([df[~mask], df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)`