# If a row contains at least two not NaN values, split the row into two separate ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to convert datafarame to desired output format with requirements mentioned below.

---

Provided requirements:

- Each row can only keep one not Nan value (except *Trh1* and *Trh2*)
- I want to avoid methods that iterate over each row for performance reasons.
- I have only included four columns, for example, in a real scenario there are many more columns to share

---

**Example**:

*Input*:

| Index | Schema | Column | Trh1 | Trh2 | Trh3 | Trh4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | schema_1 | col_1 | NaN | 0.01 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | schema_2 | col_2 | 0.02 | 0.03 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | schema_3 | col_3 | 0.03 | 0.04 | 0.05 | NaN |
| 3 | schema_4 | col_4 | NaN | NaN | 0.06 | 0.07 |

*Expected output*:

| Index | Schema | Column | Trh1 | Trh2 | Trh3 | Trh4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | schema_1 | col_1 | NaN | 0.01 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | schema_2 | col_2 | 0.02 | 0.03 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | schema_3 | col_3 | 0.03 | 0.04 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | schema_3 | col_3 | NaN | NaN | 0.05 | NaN |
| 4 | schema_4 | col_4 | NaN | NaN | 0.06 | NaN |
| 5 | schema_4 | col_4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.07 |

I explored following approach: [Split row into 2 based on condition pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071304/split-row-into-2-based-on-condition-pandas?fbclid=IwAR0-4Tk3Mc45MiiHJp3M3bbBshhMVU6PTL-vI-0e3qee2G1AZ9q-dvIcciM). However, this approach is only suitable for splitting a row if there are no Nan values in the two columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### handling a jump

```
cols = ['Index', 'Schema', 'Column', 'Trh1', 'Trh2']
special = ['Trh1', 'Trh2']
others = list(df.columns.difference(cols))


out = (df
   .assign(init=lambda d: d[others].isna().all(axis=1))
   [cols+['init']+others]
   .set_index(cols).stack().to_frame()
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=range(df.index.ndim)).cumcount())
   .set_index('n', append=True)[0]
   .unstack(-2)
   .reset_index()
)

out.loc[out['init'].isna(), special] = np.nan

out = out.drop(columns=['n', 'init'])

out = out.dropna(subset=special+others, how='all')
```

Output:

```
 Index    Schema Column  Trh1  Trh2  Trh3  Trh4
0      0  schema_1  col_1   NaN  0.01   NaN   NaN
1      1  schema_2  col_2  0.02  0.03   NaN   NaN
2      2  schema_3  col_3  0.03  0.04   NaN   NaN
3      2  schema_3  col_3   NaN   NaN  0.05   NaN
5      3  schema_4  col_4   NaN   NaN  0.06   NaN
6      3  schema_4  col_4   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.07
```

##### original answer

You can use reshaping with de-duplication, with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
cols = ['Index', 'Schema', 'Column', 'Trh1', 'Trh2']

out = (df
   # stack and remove NaNs
   .set_index(cols).stack().to_frame()
   # deduplicate
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=range(df.index.ndim)).cumcount())
   # reshape to original shape
   .set_index('n', append=True)[0]
   .unstack(-2)
   # cleanup
   .reset_index()
   .drop(columns='n')
)

# add rows that were dropped because having no value
out = pd.concat([df[df[df.columns.difference(cols)].isna().all(axis=1)], out],
                ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='Index') # optional
```

*NB. this requires no duplicates in the initial `cols`.*

Or with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), which might be more memory intensive but also more robust if you have duplicates:

```
cols = ['Index', 'Schema', 'Column', 'Trh1', 'Trh2']

out = (df.melt(cols)
       # drop NAs, except first row per group
       .loc[lambda d: d['value'].notna() | ~d[cols].duplicated()]
       # de-duplicate
       .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(cols, dropna=False).cumcount())
       # reshape
       .pivot(index=cols+['n'], columns='variable', values='value')
       # cleanup
       .reset_index().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   Index    Schema Column  Trh1  Trh2  Trh3  Trh4
0      0  schema_1  col_1   NaN  0.01   NaN   NaN
1      1  schema_2  col_2  0.02  0.03   NaN   NaN
2      2  schema_3  col_3  0.03  0.04  0.05   NaN
3      3  schema_4  col_4   NaN   NaN  0.06   NaN
4      3  schema_4  col_4   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.07
```

Comment: It works fine but for the row with index 2 I want the value for Trh3 to be split into seperate rows as in the provided example.

Comment: @Slawek you're right, I missed that point. Let me think ;)

Comment: @Slawek I updated the `stack` approach. I don't have time now but will try to update the `melt` as well later ;)

Comment: Awesome, it would be nice to see an answer for the `melt` approach too, but anyway thanks, u made my day ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well.

```
c = ['Trh1','Trh2']

(df.set_index(['Schema','Column'],append=True)
.stack()
.to_frame()
.assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby(level=[0]).cumcount().where(~x.index.isin(c,level=-1)))
.set_index('cc',append=True)[0]
.unstack(level=-2)
.droplevel([0,-1])
.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
     Schema Column  Trh1  Trh2  Trh3  Trh4
0  schema_1  col_1   NaN  0.01   NaN   NaN
1  schema_2  col_2  0.02  0.03   NaN   NaN
2  schema_3  col_3  0.03  0.04   NaN   NaN
3  schema_3  col_3   NaN   NaN  0.05   NaN
4  schema_4  col_4   NaN   NaN  0.06   NaN
5  schema_4  col_4   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.07
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'schema':['schema_1','schema_2','schema_3','schema_4'],
                   'Column':['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4'],
                    'trh1':[None,2,3,None],
                    'trh2':[1,3,4,None],
                    'trh3':[None,None,5,6],
                    'trh4':[None,None,None,7]})


d2 = pd.concat([d1.drop(['trh3','trh4'],axis=1),
                d1[['Column','schema','trh3']],
                d1[['Column','schema','trh4']],])

d2.dropna(subset=d2.columns.difference(['schema','Column']), how='all', inplace=True)

d2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

uniquely separate all the columns trh3, trh4, (trh1 and trh2 combined) and concatenate them. Remove the NaN values and reset index.